# How to remove "Validation Rule" of a column in MS ACCESS - Using query

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a customer file in MS ACCESS, it contains many tables.

**Case:**

In table(X) for Column(Y) there is validation rule of "=1 Or 2". I want to change it to "=1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4" if Possible, Its an Byte column. Otherwsie i want to completly remove the validation rule for that column. I am using C# and i need a query to do so.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access SQL can not be used to add, remove, or alter a Validation Rule.  That can only be done through the DAO TableDef.

If you were using VBA in Access, you could do this to create your Validation Rule.

```vba
CurrentDb.TableDefs("X").Fields("Y").ValidationRule = "IN (1,2,3,4)"
```

I used `IN (1,2,3,4)` instead of `1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4`, but either should work.

Perhaps you can use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access` to do the same from c#.

An alternative would be to create a check constraint with Access SQL.  A check constraint is not the same as a Validation Rule, but could be used to accomplish the same goal.

```sql
ALTER TABLE X ADD CONSTRAINT one_to_four CHECK (Y IN (1,2,3,4));
```

You would still need to discard the existing Validation Rule.  If that's not feasible, you could create a new table with the same structure as the old, add the check constraint, and finally load data from the old to the new table.